# ¿Cómo transformar un formato varchar a timestamp usando Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo este formato de tiempo en varchar y quisiera pasarlo a formato timestamp usando Laravel.. ¿Cómo pudiera hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que me quedara de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo... He investigado y me han dicho que con un STR_TO_DATE es posible hacerlo pero no se como aplicarlo

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select('incidencias.fecha_tope')
   ->get();
```

Comment: En Laravel el tiempo suele manejarse con Carbon, por ejemplo `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', '13/01/2020 00:00:00')->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');` . Pero si consideras usar Eloquent, podrías hacer un accesor para esa columna, que devuelva el atributo `fecha_tope` en el formato que quieras.

Comment: ¿La idea es cambiar la información almacenada en la base de datos o solo al momento de mostrarla al usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de una libreria de laravel llamada "Carbon", puedes usarlo tanto en el controlador como en la vista. Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
class abc extend Controller {
   public function tuFuncion() 
   { 
      $data = DB::table('incidencias')
             ->select('incidencias.fecha_tope')
             ->get();
      $dateModify = Carbon::parse($data->fecha_tope)->format('Y-MM-dd, H:m:s');
    }
}
```

Más información de la librería [Aquí](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Para hacerlo así, tendría que iterar sobre `$data`, ya que la consulta devolvería una colección, y no se puede acceder al atributo de un modelo en la colección directamente.

Comment: tienes razón @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0):

Con esto logré la solución

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select('incidencias.fecha_notif', DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(fecha_notif, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as time"))
   ->get();
```

Comment: Nunca entendimos qué era lo que querías...

Comment: gracias de igual manera